How does one calculate the amount of bodyweight pressed in a push-up at varying levels of incline?
I came across the following chart:
Push-Up Variation by Incline Level
It was sought out because, well, quite frankly, I am very out of shape and limited to resources around the house.  In other words, I don't have a block of 30 centimeters or 60 centimeters (both of which would be too difficult for me at the moment).  What I have instead is a butcher block table of 36 inches (91.44 centimeters) and a kitchen table of 29 inches (73.66 centimeters).  I've tried various methods of trying to calculate this.  I attempted to calculate this by setting the flat or 64% to 100% and adjusting from there, like so:
Chart of Calculations
but clearly, this is not how you go about it because an incline of 91.44 centimeters should mean that less weight is pushed than at 30 centimeters, not more.
A web search was conducted, but nothing really helped me.  I did, however, come across this answer at Quora, but I have no idea how to calculate the angle of incline off of a height measurement (which surely would disappoint my high school trigonomics teacher).
I also came across this Quora answer that involved the use of the concept of "fulcrum," but it did not help me figure out how to calculate for varying levels of height.  (From the answers I saw, if mathematicians are using Quora, it seems they have avoided this question.)
And I also came across this chart:
Rough % of Bodyweight Pushed at Varying Levels of Incline
on this web page.
These pages were also found:
Physics of Fitness Fridays - Incline vs Decline Push-Ups
Work Done Doing Push-ups on an Incline
And even this page (on the Physics Stack Exchange):
Distribution of weight of an inclined object
which makes me wonder if I should be asking this over there, but what I am really looking for is a simple mathematical equation that can answer my question.  In other words, I am good with accepting, at face value, that doing a push-up on a box of 30 centimeters equates to a push equating to 55% of bodyweight.  In my effort to include some pages of what I've found thus far, I have included some pages where some have addressed the aspect of how much of the body is involved in the process and at which body part one should consider the fulcrum, but I don't really care about that.  I am looking for a simple way to measure, to some degree, the relative difficulty of one push-up workout to another and accepting the first chart I included as a given is acceptable to me.  Therefore, I see this as more of a math question than a physics question.
I am convinced that a simple solution exists for this but my knowledge of math is a bit limiting and I have no doubt that those in this community have solved far more complex questions than this.
Your assistance in solving this query will be appreciated (and even more so if the answer doesn't involve having to figure out the angle of incline).
Also, can the solution to the answer regarding levels of incline be identically applied to levels of decline?

Welcome to Math SE, remember to use MathJax formatting ($x$ not x). Thank you.

I actually tried to use it, but it did not work, so I made a picture of my calculations instead and linked to the picture ... best I could do.  To be honest, I was a bit disappointed because I was excited to try MathJax formatting.  Don't know why it didn't work for me.

MathJax is used by placing $ on either side of an equation, no spaces. Try it out!

I wonder if this should be better posted on [fitness.se] rather than here.
